# jupyerlab labextension list warning

Tags: jupyter

I get a warning when listing jupyter labextensions.   Should this be a concern?  I can't get the vispy widget going or itkwidgets, I get a "module not found" error in the browser.  That's the issue I'd really like to solve but this bit here is quick to post.

```
(base) brian@twix:~$ jupyter labextension list
Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `ListLabExtensionsApp`.
[W 2022-06-04 14:41:25.267 LabApp] Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `LabApp`.
JupyterLab v3.4.2
/home/brian/miniforge3/share/jupyter/labextensions
        jupyter_rfb v0.1.0 enabled OK (python, jupyter_rfb)
        jupyterlab_pygments v0.2.2 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_pygments)
        jupyter-matplotlib v0.11.1 enabled OK
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v3.1.0 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_widgets)

Other labextensions (built into JupyterLab)
   app dir: /home/brian/miniforge3/share/jupyter/lab
        bqplot v0.5.34 enabled OK
        vispy v0.3.0 enabled OK
```

I've removed jupyter and its directories from `jupyter --path` and reinstalled in my base environment, ipykernel in notebook environent, and have this error again.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has recently been labeled as a BUG at https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12142, it is still unassigned (under a 'Needs Triage' status), but apparently has no effects on the environment at all.

The warning message is: `Config option kernel_spec_manager_class not recognized by LabApp`.